# What are the roots of the equation $z^{40} - z^{20} - a(a+1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

I found this question in a book. The answer given is that the roots are $(a+1)^{1/20}\exp\left({\frac{i2k_1\pi}{20}}\right)$ and $(a+1)^{1/20}\exp\left({\frac{i(2k_1+1)\pi}{20}}\right)$. How do I begin this problem? I only know the basics of how to express a complex number in terms of Euler's number. Would someone please give me a simple explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since
$$z^{40}-z^{20}-a(a+1)=\left(z^{20}+a\right)\left[z^{20}-(a+1)\right]$$
you need to solve
$$z^{20}+a=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad z^{20}-(a+1)=0$$
i.e. finding the $20$th's roots of $-a$ and $a+1$.

---

If also it is given that $a$ is a real and positive number we have $$-a=a(\cos \pi+i\sin\pi)\qquad\text{and}\qquad a+1=(a+1)(\cos 0+i\sin 0)$$

Comment: Why do both factors have to be zero?

Comment: @max_zorn: I mean that the roots of the given equation are all the roots of these equations, which must be solved separately.

Comment: On applying the euler's number form, I got (a+1)^(1/20)exp(i2k1π+θ1/20)  and a^(1/20)exp(i(2k1π+θ2/20). How do we get that θ1 and θ2 are equal to 0 and π respectively?

Comment: @Hema It is right only if $a$ is a real and positive number.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos Perhaps you should replace *and* by *or* in your second displayed equation? This is not a system of equations you want to solve simultaneously after all?

Answer (score 2):

HinT: Substituting $$z^{20}=t$$ then we get $$t^2-t-a(a+1)=0$$ to solve.

Comment: On applying the euler's number form, I got (a+1)^(1/20)exp(i2k1π+θ1/20)  and a^(1/20)exp(i(2k1π+θ2/20). How do we get that θ1 and θ2 are equal to 0 and π respectively?